# Rotate an image without averaging pixel values

Tags: python, image, opencv, ndimage

Is it possible to rotate an image and keep the true values? When I rotate a black and white image I get back grey values. Can I rotate without averaging the pixel values? I can almost do it manually by using `np.where()` but it gets difficult when there are more than 2 pixel values.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy import ndimage
import cv2

filename = 'rot square.png'  

img = cv2.imread('square test.png') 
img_rot = ndimage.rotate(img, 10, reshape = False)
cv2.imwrite(filename, img_rot)
```

Original Image

[image: Original Image]

Rotated Image

[image: Rotated Image]

Averaged Values

[image: Averaged Values]

True Values

[image: True Values]

Comment: Try adding `mode='nearest'` and `prefilter=False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('original.png')
rotated = img.rotate(45)
rotated.save('rotated.png')
```